# Object required error on my row count attempt

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting object required on this sub at:

`Set RowNum = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Count`

Any extra help would be appreciated as well. I am trying to copy and paste from one table to another based off of the the first column cell value of each row of the table I am coping to and comparing it to the table that contains the data I need organized by

```
Private Sub ECRList_Click()

Dim RowName As String
Dim ColName As String
 Dim Collist As Range
 Dim Namelist As Range
 Dim RowNum As Integer
'Dim ColNum As Integer


Set Collist = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObject("Table1").HeaderRowRange    'creates an array that contains the table header cell names
Set Namelist = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Range 'creates an array that contains the first row cell names of the table
Set RowNum = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Count

For Each ColName In Collist 'iterate through each name in column header array
    For Each RowName In Namelist  'iterate through each name in row name list
        For RowNum = 1 To Namelist.UBound 'supplies an accurate array length
            If Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3").DataBodyRange(RowNum, "Column1").Value = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(RowNum, "ECR_No").Value Then 'compares the text of both of tables first rows
           Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3").ListRow(RowNum).Select
           Sheets("Sheet2").ListObjects("Table3").ListRow(RowNum).Copy 'copies the row from table 3
           Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").ListRow(RowNum).Select
           Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").ListRow(RowNum).Paste 'pastes the row from table 3 too table 2


                'Next ColNum
            End If
        Next RowNum
    Next RowName
Next ColName
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RowNum` is not an object variable.  The `Set` keyword is only used when assigning to object variables.

Remove the `Set` keyword.

```
RowNum = Sheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(1).Count
```

The error message means that the statement cannot be compiled/evaluated because the left side of the assignment is not an object type, as it would need to be when using the `Set` keyword (in that case, you would also need to ensure the right side of the assignment statement returns an object type, too).